# ace editor scrolling issue in ipad

Tags: css, ipad, mobile, ace-editor

I cant able to scroll in ace-editor when the application is loaded in Mobile devices including android and IPad.

Its working fine in all other browsers. I believe its an common issue in ace editor.

If any has faced this before and fixed this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var editor = ace.edit("ViewScriptEditor");
    $('#ViewScriptEditor').css('width', $('.popup-wrap', $('#open-scripts-list-popup')).width());
    $('#ViewScriptEditor').css('height', 220);
    editor.resize();
    editor.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(true);
    editor.setReadOnly(true);
```

This is how I configured the ace editor.

Comment: It is a bug in the Ace editor. I don't get scrollbars on Android either.

Comment: Same here. There is discussion on this issue: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/37